# Rails mailer styling

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml, sass, actionmailer

Why i recieve default style mail's on my mail? In code i style it a little bit, but why on gmail i see default layout?
My code is such:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=utf-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}
      %title Покупка автозапчастей
      :css
        body, td { background-color:#cecece; color:#000000; font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,Arial; }
        .blue { background-color: blue; height:2px; color: white; }
        .notice {margin: 10px auto;  background-color: #fbb752;  border: 1px solid #cecece; }
  %body
    .blue
      %h3
        Новый заказ
      %b
        Внимание, недавно на сайте сформирован новый заказ!
        = @order.id
    .notice
      %table
        %tr
          %th
            id клиента
          %th
            Улица
          %th
            Здание
          %th
            Общая сумма
          %th
            Статус
          %th
            Открыт
        %tr
          %td
            = @order.user.id
            = @order.user.email
          %td
            %b
              = @order.street
          %td
            = @order.building
          %td
            %b
              = @order.totalcost
          %td
            %b
              = @order.orderstatus.name
          %td
            = @order.created_at
      %br/
      %table
        %tr
          %th
            Артикул
          %th
            Цена
          %th
            Количество      
        - @order.line_items.each do |l|
          %tr{ :class => cycle("zebra-stripe zebra-grey zebra1", "zebra-stripe zebra-grey zebra2")}      
            %td
              = l.description
            %td
              = l.price
            %td
              = l.quantity
```

So how to do, that my mailer send on my e-mail service (gmail) good styled-letters as in my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gmail drops all `<style>` tags from HTML emails.

If you want your styles to appear in Gmail, you need to use inline style attributes.

Comment: Note that there are tools to automatically convert css to inline styles. Use google.

Comment: also on other services i didn't see my layout! problem is in code

Comment: @brabertaser1992: That's because they do use `style=""` attributes.

Comment: hem, why than here is working? http://railscasts.com/episodes/312-sending-html-email?view=asciicast

Comment: hey, where have you been lost?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: @brabertaser1992: Instead of using CSS selectors to apply properties, you need to apply them directly to each element using `style=""` attributes.

Comment: @brabertaser1992: There are Rbuy gems that will do this automatically.

Comment: https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails looks like a promising choice for a gem.